# PyCharm Debug Tool Window simply desapear

Tags: ide, debugging, tools, pycharm

My PyCharm debug tool window isn't available anymore. I was using it without problem yesterday, however after turn the computer on and open the application it has disappeared from the side bar and also from all menus; Even in keymap list it's not present anymore.

I've already reinstalled the application, [removing it's files completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913555/2989289), but it come back with the same problem

Any suggestion of what to do to recover it?

Comment: By "Debug Tool Window" do you mean the tool tab labeled "Debug" which only shows when you've run a Python script with PyCharm in Debug mode?  Because that windows is **by default** only visible when you run a script.

Comment: You were right, Thomas. I ran an file in debug mode and it appeared again. But it was so strange, it wasn't at any menu, that I didn't understand. Well... thanks. I will delete this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm, the "Debug" tool window is *typically* only visible when you are actually running an application in Debug mode within PyCharm.

Set up an execution profile for your application, and then run it in Debug mode, which will enable the debugger.  This will bring up the 'Debug' tool window/tab you're looking for.

(There is a similar window/tab for 'Run' as well, but is basically the same except for debug options and tools that only shows up when *running* the application in non-debug mode as well)